# How to parse an array API in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, api

I try to get information from an API that looks like [this](https://apidev.meep.me/tripplan/api/v1/routers/lisboa/resources?lowerLeftLatLon=38.711046,-9.160096&upperRightLatLon=38.739429,-9.137115):

I am able to parse the information using this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getAPI()
}

func getAPI() {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            guard let urlContent = data else { return }

            do {
                let JSONResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: .mutableContainers)
                print("JSON Result:", JSONResult)

                print("-----------------")
                print(type(of: JSONResult))

            } catch {
                print("JSON processing failed.")
            }
        } else {
            print("Error serializing JSON:", error!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

But I have troubles on retrieving individual data from the API (like "x", "y" and "companyZoneId"). I tried extracting the first element from JSONResult (JSONResult.first) but it only shows the components of the 1st element in the array (so I assume that I have an array inside an array(?)).

How can I get and store these elements? Because then I'd like to show these positions in a map, but that's another step that I will deal with later. For now Im stuck on retrieving individual information from each element of that API's array, and I come to your expertise to guide me.

I've read different tutorials here and seen some videos in youtube but none has helped me out with this specific situation.

I appreciate your help.

Greets!

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer:
First I created a struct with all my API elements in it:

```
struct MyInfo: Codable {
let id: String
let name: String
let x: Double // Longitude
let y: Double // Latitude
let licencePlate: String?
let range: Int?
let batteryLevel: Int?
let seats: Int?
let model: String?
let resourceImageId: String?
let pricePerMinuteParking: Int?
let pricePerMinuteDriving: Int?
let realTimeData: Bool?
let engineType: String?
let resourceType: String?
let companyZoneId: Int
let helmets: Int?
let station: Bool?
let availableResources: Int?
let spacesAvailable: Int?
let allowDropoff: Bool?
let bikesAvailable: Int?
}
```

Then I created the method to get the elements I need from the API:

```
func getAPI() {

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            guard let urlContent = data else { return }

            do {
                let JSONResult = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyInfo].self, from: urlContent) //JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: .mutableContainers)
                print("JSON Result:", JSONResult)

                for jsonData in JSONResult {
                    self.lonX.append(jsonData.x)
                    self.latY.append(jsonData.y)
                    self.companyZoneID.append(jsonData.companyZoneId)
                } catch {
                print("JSON processing failed.")
            }
        } else {
            print("Error serializing JSON:", error!)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
    }
}
```

Now I have another problem that I can't resolve: I can't assign the x and y values (from the jsonResult) to global variables inside the class (self.lonX and self.latY).

How can I achieve this? I did another app where I did something similar (created a global variables struct to which I assigned values gotten from an API to be used elsewhere) but now it seems it is not working.

I seek for your experience and tips.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow lol... the reason your answer is likely being downvoted is because it's not explicitly clear how you got from problem to answer - ie your answer is incomplete. Including sample code from the struct and comparing it to the original, for example, would be useful to someone wanting an answer to your question. I upvoted your answer to offset the unwelcoming downvotes. Please do edit it to make it more useful

Comment: @froggomad I have not voted on this but please don't upvote anything just to counter someone's downvote. You should upvote because it deserves an upvote, not because you feel bad. Your whole comment gives a reason why it doesn't deserve an upvote but then you upvote anyway. That makes no sense.

Comment: @rmaddy normally I would agree with you, but in the case of a new user, should downvotes not be reserved and helpful comments be given instead? Or at least a combination of the two. Downvoting new users doesn’t help stackoverflow. I almost left on day 1 because of it

Comment: @froggomad Votes should be applied to the question/answer, not the user. Your upvote was for the user, not for the answer. That's the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Even the downvotes. They help me to improve in the elaboration of my questions. Good day everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/). Just paste your json there and it will generate for you the model objects to decode it. This is what you get with your json:

```
// MARK: - WelcomeElement
class WelcomeElement: Codable {
    let id, name: String
    let x, y: Double
    let licencePlate: String?
    let range, batteryLevel, seats: Int?
    let model: Model?
    let resourceImageID: ResourceImageID?
    let pricePerMinuteParking, pricePerMinuteDriving: Int?
    let realTimeData: Bool
    let engineType: String?
    let resourceType: ResourceType?
    let companyZoneID: Int
    let helmets: Int?
    let station: Bool?
    let availableResources, spacesAvailable: Int?
    let allowDropoff: Bool?
    let bikesAvailable: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, x, y, licencePlate, range, batteryLevel, seats, model
        case resourceImageID = "resourceImageId"
        case pricePerMinuteParking, pricePerMinuteDriving, realTimeData, engineType, resourceType
        case companyZoneID = "companyZoneId"
        case helmets, station, availableResources, spacesAvailable, allowDropoff, bikesAvailable
    }

    init(id: String, name: String, x: Double, y: Double, licencePlate: String?, range: Int?, batteryLevel: Int?, seats: Int?, model: Model?, resourceImageID: ResourceImageID?, pricePerMinuteParking: Int?, pricePerMinuteDriving: Int?, realTimeData: Bool, engineType: String?, resourceType: ResourceType?, companyZoneID: Int, helmets: Int?, station: Bool?, availableResources: Int?, spacesAvailable: Int?, allowDropoff: Bool?, bikesAvailable: Int?) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.licencePlate = licencePlate
        self.range = range
        self.batteryLevel = batteryLevel
        self.seats = seats
        self.model = model
        self.resourceImageID = resourceImageID
        self.pricePerMinuteParking = pricePerMinuteParking
        self.pricePerMinuteDriving = pricePerMinuteDriving
        self.realTimeData = realTimeData
        self.engineType = engineType
        self.resourceType = resourceType
        self.companyZoneID = companyZoneID
        self.helmets = helmets
        self.station = station
        self.availableResources = availableResources
        self.spacesAvailable = spacesAvailable
        self.allowDropoff = allowDropoff
        self.bikesAvailable = bikesAvailable
    }
}

enum Model: String, Codable {
    case askoll = "Askoll"
    case bmw1Series = "BMW 1 Series"
    case bmwX1 = "BMW X1"
    case citroenCZero = "Citroen C-Zero"
    case mini3Door = "MINI 3-Door"
    case miniConvertible = "MINI Convertible"
}

enum ResourceImageID: String, Codable {
    case vehicleGenDN = "vehicle_gen_dn"
    case vehicleGenDNBmwS1 = "vehicle_gen_dn_bmw_s1"
    case vehicleGenEcooltra = "vehicle_gen_ecooltra"
    case vehicleGenEmov = "vehicle_gen_emov"
}

enum ResourceType: String, Codable {
    case car = "CAR"
    case electricCar = "ELECTRIC_CAR"
    case moped = "MOPED"
}

typealias Welcome = [WelcomeElement]
```

Then just use JSONDecoder

```
let welcome = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you've done it with a struct is great. You can also get to the values by casting the result with the same structure as the JSON (`{}` are dictionaries and `[]` are arrays)

For example if your result came back as:

```
{"Food": [
         "category": "Meat",
         "safeTimeLeftOut": "2 Hours"
       ],
       [
         "category": "Dairy",
         "safeTimeLeftOut: "3 Hours"
       ]
}
```

This would be a result of type [String:Any] and would need to be cast as such.

```
let result = JSONResult as? [String:Any]
```

Now you can cast the result to the appropriate type

```
let jsonDict = result["Food"] as? [[[String:String]]] //Array of Array of Dictionaries with key/value String
```

foodDict would be: [ [["category":"Meat"],["safeTimeLeftOut":"2 Hours"]], [["category":"Dairy"],["safeTimeLeftOut:"3 Hours"]] ]

You could then iterate through it to get each individual dictionary

```
for arrOfDicts in jsonDict {
    print(arrOfDicts) //prints the whole array of dictionaries
    for foodDict in arrOfDicts {
        print(foodDict) //prints 1 JSON array
        //if you want a value:
        if let category = foodDict["category"] {
            print(category) //prints the value of the key "category"
        }
    }
}
```